# configure starting solr server with command line

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I need to start solr server with command line to index my databases.. but the database is variant..
I was able to index some database :

I configure some db-data-config.xml file and I use that to import data :

```
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
         name="dsDB"
         driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
         url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/testmm_3"
         user="xxxx"
         password="xxxx" /> 
<document>
    <entity name="entity1" dataSource="dsDB" query="select DocID as 'id', DocName  from table1 ;">
        <field column="id" name="id" />
        <field column="DocName" name="DocName" />
        <entity name="entity2" dataSource="dsDB"  query="select * from table2 where table1_DocID=${entity1.id}">
        </entity>           
    </entity>
```

I add same field in my schema.xml file.

I start the solr server with this commande line

```
/xxx/xx > java -jar -Dsolr.data.dir="ouputIndexedData_Folder\data" start.jar
```

Now i need to start solr server but with connection to ANOTHER database.. i mean this line

```
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
 ...
 url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/testmm_3"
```

I don't need to modify manualy this line.
How can i do that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could always provide a different `-confdir` as a command line parameter.

This means you have on `default` configuration of the `db-data-config.xml` which is read when you run:

> java -jar -Dsolr.data.dir="ouputIndexedData_Folder\data" start.jar

For the other case you could do something like this:

> java -jar -Dsolr.data.dir="ouputIndexedData_Folder\data" start.jar -configdir "path-to-alternative-config\db-datat-config.xml"

Suggest you experiment a bit, but the docs are quite good when it comes to configuring the Solr start up: [solr-command-line-opts](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Command+Line+Utilities).

Good luck :)

Comment: hey @thomas77.. i used your command.. i have this error : ERROR org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  û java.io.IOException: Can't find resource 'db-data-config.xml' in classpath or 'I:\xxx\Sol
r\example\solr\collection1\conf'.. is there other setting to do?!

Answer (score 0):

To set the launch solr server with a configuration file, I use this command

```
>Xxx\Xxx\Solr\example>java  -Dsolr.allow.unsafe.resourceloading=true -jar start.jar -config="XXX\XXXX\db-data-config.xml"
```

This command work fine.